# Question about non-i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$. Find an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) \forall \epsilon > 0$. Note that random variables are not independent.

$\textbf{What I've tried:}$

We know that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] = p$. So we can use Chebyshev's inequality because $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]| > \epsilon) \le \mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]| \ge \epsilon) \stackrel{Chebyshev}{\le} \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X})}{\epsilon^2} \le \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i)}{n^2\epsilon^2} \le \frac{n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)}{n^2\epsilon^2} \le \frac{n^2  \operatorname{Var}(X_1)}{n^2\epsilon^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{\epsilon^2}$

So, $\frac{p(1-p)}{\epsilon^2}$ is an upper bound.

Is my proof true? Thanks!

Comment: no it's wrong..$\mathrm{Var}(X_1+X_2)\leq \mathrm{Var}(X_1)+\mathrm{Var}(X_2)$ is not true

Comment: @Andrew But in my case I didn't said $\operatorname{Var}(X_1 + X_2) \le \operatorname{Var}(X_1) + \operatorname{Var}(X_2)$. I said that $\operatorname{Var}(X_1 + X_2) \le 2(\operatorname{Var}(X_1) + \operatorname{Var}(X_2))$

Comment: okay, should be fine then

Comment: That seems quite a loose upper bound in many cases: if $\epsilon < \sqrt{p(1-p)}$ it will give a value greater than $1$ as an unhelpful upper bound on a probability. Meanwhile if $\epsilon \ge  \max(p,1-p)$ it will give a positive value when I think the upper bound is $0$.  It may be better if $\epsilon$ is just below $1$ and either $p$ or $1-p$ is between $\epsilon$ and $1$

Comment: The  case where all $X_i$ are identical implies a bound of 1 for $\epsilon <\min(p, (1-p)$.

Comment: So.. How can I do it better? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculated upper bound is an upper bound and your argument looks reasonable, but it is not the tightest possible.

If the $X_i$ can have any dependency, with large enough $n$ you can construct $\bar X$ to approximate any distribution on $[0,1]$ which has expectation $p$. There are three ranges of values of $\epsilon$ to consider:

- $0< \epsilon < \min(p, 1-p)$: you can concentrate the distribution of $\bar X$ outside the interval $(p - \epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ so you can only say (as with any probability) $$\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) \le 1$$
- $\max(p, 1-p) < \epsilon$: in which case $p - \epsilon < 0$ and $p + \epsilon > 1$ and so you can say $$\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) =0$$
- $\min(p, 1-p) < \epsilon < \max(p, 1-p)$: you are only interested in one tail and if $0 < p< \frac12$ then $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\bar{X}>p +\epsilon) \le \frac{\mathbb E[\bar X]}{p+\epsilon}= \frac{p}{p+\epsilon}$ using Markov's inequality, and similarly by symmetry if $\frac12 < p < 1$ then $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\bar{X}< 1-p -\epsilon) \le \frac{1-p}{1-p+\epsilon}$, which you can combine to say $$\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}-p| > \epsilon)  \le \frac{1}{1+\frac{\epsilon}{\min(p,1-p)}}$$

As an illustration, here are the two upper bounds shown for $p=\frac13$, with yours in red and mine in blue.

[image: upper bound on probability]

---

Jessie asked for the code to draw this.  Using R:

```
boundA <- function(p,epsilon){
  ifelse(epsilon < p & epsilon < 1-p, 1, 
  ifelse(epsilon > p & epsilon > 1-p, 0, 
  1 / (1 + epsilon / ifelse(p < 1-p, p, 1-p))))  
  }   
boundB <- function(p,epsilon){
  p*(1-p) / epsilon^2
  }   

pstring <- "1/3"
p <- eval(parse(text=pstring))
curve(boundA(p,x), from=0, to=1.15, ylim=c(0,2), col="blue", 
      n=50001, xlab="epsilon", ylab="upper bound on probability",
      main=paste(c("p = ", pstring), collapse=""))
curve(boundB(p,x), from=0, to=1.15, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Amir My piecewise bound (which does not contain $n$) is only $\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{\epsilon}{\min(p,1-p)}}$ when $\min(p, 1-p) < \epsilon < \max(p, 1-p)$.  For which value of $p$ do you think the red line is ever below the blue line?

Comment: @Amir - For $p=\frac12$ it is impossible to have $\min(p, 1-p) < \epsilon < \max(p, 1-p)$ i.e. to have $\frac12 < \epsilon < \frac12$, so my bound is $1$ when $\epsilon < \frac12$ and $0$ when $\epsilon>\frac12$.

Comment: @ Henry, this is a nice illustration. Would you be able to provide the code for it?

Comment: Dear Henry could you derive the tightest function $f(\epsilon) $ that is greater than or equal to your bound $b(p, \epsilon) $ for any $p$, i.e., $$f(\epsilon) = \sup_{p \in [0,1]}b(p, \epsilon) $$ for all  $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Amir:  It seems that it would be $f(\epsilon) = 1$ when $\epsilon \le \frac12$, and be $f(\epsilon)=1-\epsilon$ when $\frac12 \le \epsilon \le 1$, and be $f(\epsilon)=0$  when $1 \le \epsilon$

Comment: @Jessie - I have added the R code I used