$X_1, ... X_{200}, X = \sum_{n=1}^{200} X_n $ - What can I know of X?
Let $$ X_1, X_2, ... X_{200} \sim Ber(1/2) $$
And let $$ X = \sum_{n=1}^{200} X_n $$
I'm asked to find what is always true between these options:
A) $ P(X = 100) \le 0.6 $
B) $P(X \ge 150) < 0.5 $
C) $P(X \le 25) \le \frac{4}{7} $
D) None of the above.
The answer is C), apparently.
I don't understand how to approach this problem. How do I figure out which answer makes sense, and which doesn't? I'd appreciate any hints..

I presume you cannot assume that $X$s are independent?

Without further information (like independence) you cannot say anything about  the probabilities in A),B) and C), so the answer is D).

That's what I thought as well, but apparently the answer is C, and there's no explanation why (it's from an exam).

Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4842493/1231520

Even if we don't know the dependence, we still know that C) is true.
Let's check the answers:
A) If all $X_1 \dots X_{100}$ are identical, and all $X_{101} \dots X_{200}$
are also identical and anticorrelated with the first subset, then $X$ is exactly $100$ so answer A is in that case not true.
B) If all $X_1 \dots X_{200}$ are identical, then $X$ is $0$ or $200$, with $P(X=0)=P(X=200)=0.5$, so $P(X>150)<0.5$ of answer B in that case is just not true.
C) Even the maximum correlation (all identical) that disproved answer B, cannot disprove C, since in that case $P(X<25)=P(X=0)=0.5$, compatible with C. Instead we use that any counter example must still have $E(X)=100$ and further that:
$$\begin{align}
  &E(X) = E(X\ |X\leq25)\ P(X\leq 25) +  E(X\ |25<X\leq 200)\ P(25<X\leq 200),  
\\[5pt]
  \text{and}\quad &E(X\ |\ X\leq 25) \leq 25\ \quad\text{(by definition, one could say) and likewise:}
\\[5pt]
 &E(X\ |\ 25<X\leq 200) \leq 200,
\\[5pt]
\Rightarrow 100 = &E(X) \leq 25\ P(X\leq 25) + 200\ P(25<X\leq 200).
\end{align}$$
And since $P(25<X\leq 200) = 1 - P(X\leq 25)$ it follows that
$$\begin{align}
100  \leq -175\ P(X\leq 25) + 200
\\[5pt]
\Rightarrow P(X\leq 25) \leq \frac{100}{175}=\frac47,
\end{align}$$
so C is always true.

A complete answer!

@Amir suggested I point at some comments to the answer of  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4842691/6460 dealing with the $\frac47$ answer
